# Convert all string with thousand separator chars to int, in all int properties of all models, .Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware, model-binding, typeconverter

I'm working with .Net Core MVC 2.1
In our views we have price with thousand separator like `2,500,000`
I want to get all of them in our back-end models as `INT` type, I mean without `,`.

I want to write something like a `middleware` to do that without `ModelBinder` attribute for each `int` property.
How can we do it?

Comment: One way is to adjust the formatting in the view, so that he dispenses with the thousands of seperator. Or define the data type correctly.

Comment: @MartinS.I'm working on `backend`

Comment: Have you looked into JsonConverter?

Comment: @MarkusDresch: I know it, but how can use it like a middleware to convert all my string properties to int without `,` chars

Answer (score 1):

Create a class derrived from JsonConverter, similar to this (might need more validation in ReadJson):

```
public class FormattedStringToIntConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(string);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        int.TryParse(token.ToString(), NumberStyles.AllowThousands, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), out var value);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Now you can add an attribute to your model properties where you want to use this converter:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(FormattedStringToIntConverter))]
```

Or if you want to check all strings, you can change your Startup.cs to include some JsonOptions:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(o => {
    o.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new FormattedStringToIntConverter());
})
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

You may add more logic to CanConvert to only try to convert strings that really contain a number.

Comment: My project is not API, it's MVC, is it OK?

Comment: there shouldn't be any difference